# Clarification of inner and outer approximations of a set $E \in \mathbb{R}^n$ using dyadic cubes

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In Folland's Real Analysis, he lets $Q_k$ be the collection of cubes whose side length is $2^{-k}$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then for a set $E \in \mathbb{R}^n$ he lets $A_k(E) = \bigcup \{Q  \in Q_k : Q \subset E\}$ be the inner approximation of E and $B_k(E) = \bigcup \{Q  \in Q_k : Q \cap E \neq \emptyset\}$ the outer approximation of E. What I don't understand is he says "the sets $A_k$ increase with $k$ while the sets $B_k$ decrease", but I cannot see how. Would someone be able to explain how this holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you increase $k$, each "cube" is subdivided into $2^n$ cubes. In $A_{k+1}$, each old cube of $A_k$ remains, and new smaller cubes appear to fill the gaps. In $B_{k+1}$, only the old cubes remain, and some of the subdivisions will be lots.

If you don't see the above, just draw a disk in $\mathbb R^2$, and draw the squares, and their subdivisions.

Comment: Ah I see it makes sense now, thank you!